# how to add data in a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, database

so i was creating a menu option where user enters some data and using a function all of that data is added to a MySQL table however the data table is not being updated properly
I have checked there is nothing wrong with the table created so I think the problem lies in the code somewhere

```
import mysql.connector
def add_det(x1, x2, x3, x4):
                global icode, iname, price, quantity
                try:
                    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='practicals', user='root', password='root1')
                    cursor=conn.cursor()
                    print("cursor objected created")
                    sql = """#INSERT INTO inventory(item_code, item_name, price, quantity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
                    t=(x1, x2, x3, x4)
                    print(t)
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                    conn.commit()
                    print(cursor.rowcount, "Records inserted")
                except mysql.connector.Error as e:
                    print("Failed to get record from Mysql table: {}", format(error))
                finally:
                    if conn.is_connected():
                        print("closing...")
                        cursor.close()
                        conn.close()
                        print("Mysql connection is closed")
            add_det(icode, iname, price, quantity)
```

could anyone pls help me in finding the error?

Comment: what do you mean by data table? mysql table? or GUI based actual data grid view or data table?

Comment: You appear to be populating `t` but never using it with the `sql` query string. your query also begins with a `#` which isn't valid.

Comment: @ zain ui abidin mysql table

Comment: oh alright thnx so much

Comment: for populating ```t``` all of the code is in a while loop so t takes different values every iteration

Comment: What is the point of settings global variables?

Comment: @hari: can you close this question?

Comment: umm im sorry but how do you close a question

Comment: if its selecting an answer i did it but pls excuse me if I'm wrong as i am a bit new to the platform and thank you for all your help @BeChillerToo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you remove the `#` in front of your SQL query?

Or try to change your code with:

```
sql = """#INSERT INTO inventory(item_code, item_name, price, quantity) 
    VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})""".format(
    x1, x2, x3, x4
)
```